Massive crash spike in USRVWebViewCallback invoke
We're seeing a sudden massive crash spike in UnityAds across multiple projects on iOS.
Our projects use UnityAds through AdMob mediation. We do not use Unity engine.
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x2064 objc_retain_x0 + 16
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x2064 objc_retain + 16
2  Game                           0xb2ac9c -[USRVWebViewCallback invoke:] + 7766960
3  Game                           0xb0f1c0 +[USRVApiSdk WebViewExposed_getSharedSessionID:] + 7653588
4  CoreFoundation                 0x20814 __invoking___ + 148
5  CoreFoundation                 0x1f860 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 428
6  Game                           0xb1e2c8 -[USRVInvocation nextInvocation] + 7715292
7  Game                           0xb2b4b4 -[USRVWebViewMethodInvokeHandler handleInvocation:] + 7769032
8  Game                           0xb2afd8 -[USRVWebViewMethodInvokeHandler handleData:invocationType:] + 7767788
9  Game                           0xb28644 -[USRVWebViewApp userContentController:didReceiveScriptMessage:] + 7757144
10 WebKit                         0xde8ac <redacted> + 236
11 WebKit                         0x1ee9c <redacted> + 680
12 WebKit                         0x1e788 <redacted> + 468
13 WebKit                         0x11f8ac <redacted> + 264
14 WebKit                         0x2a770 <redacted> + 44
15 WebKit                         0x24e30 <redacted> + 324
16 WebKit                         0x3a6e4 <redacted> + 520
17 JavaScriptCore                 0x5aa70 WTF::RunLoop::performWork() + 204
18 JavaScriptCore                 0x5b998 WTF::RunLoop::performWork(void*) + 36
19 CoreFoundation                 0x56834 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
20 CoreFoundation                 0x567c8 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
21 CoreFoundation                 0x54298 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 244
22 CoreFoundation                 0x53484 __CFRunLoopRun + 828
23 CoreFoundation                 0x52cd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
24 GraphicsServices               0x11a8 GSEventRunModal + 164
25 UIKitCore                      0x40aae8 -[UIApplication _run] + 888
26 UIKitCore                      0x4bed98 UIApplicationMain + 340
27 Game                           0x433754 main + 234 (main.cpp:234)
28 ???                            0x1c5a7f154 (Missing)

Is anyone else experiencing this? We have observed that other titles like EAFC are also crashing.
We have managed to workaround by disabling UnityAds on the AdMob dashboard. Is there a better workaround which lets us continue to serve ads from Unity.
I'm struggling to find any appropriate Unity forum or bug reporting system for this, hence the stack overflow post.

Yes, we too, in our games and in third-party games.

The problem seems to gone now (without disabling UnityAds). Maybe Unity fixed problem on their side.
